# std::min with Parameter Pack

Tags: c++, c++17

I was watching Jason Turner's [*C++ Weekly - Ep 64 - C++11's std::min (and my version)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z_fnMdzfWAQ&t=327s)

And now I started making a goose-chase here to make parameter pack expansion to work for multiple types using *`std::common_type`* :

```
template <typename T, typename U>
const typename std::common_type<T, U>::type& 
multi_type_min(const T& t, const U& u)
{
   return t < u ? t : u;
}

template<typename First, typename ...T>
typename std::common_type<  First, T...>::type 
variadic_min( const First& f, const T& ...t )
{
    const typename std::common_type<  First, T...>::type* retVal =&f;
    (( retVal= &multi_type_min(*retVal, t)), ...);

    return *retVal;
}
```

How do I achieve this ? Am I doing something stupid [here](https://godbolt.org/g/HAeaKr) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A variadic std::min implemented with `std::common_type` is not a good idea.

What happens when you compare a unsigned type to a signed one? Would you expect the signed one to become unsigned, or should the unsigned become signed? If we turn our signed integer into an unsigned integer, we risk wrapping around to an extremely large positive value. If we turn our unsigned integer into a signed one, we risk overflow.

When you recursively perform a comparison with `std::common_type`, the `std::common_type` for a sequence may not be the same `std::common_type` between two adjacent pairs.

For example,

```
auto res = variadic_min(1, -211, 3, -63, 89u);
```

The `std::common_type` of `1, -211, 3, -63, 89u` is `unsigned int`

BUT

The `std::common_type` of `1, -211` is `int`, so when you compare them, you will get `-211` returned as the minimum. The same is true when you compare `-211, 3`, and also `-211, -63`. However, when you compare `-211 89u`, the `std::common_type` is `unsigned int`, so `-211` becomes 4294967085, and therefore `89u` is the smallest value, which is of course ridiculous since it is neither the smallest or the largest; just a victim of integer promotion.

If you want to use `common_type` uniformly across all types, then you might do something like this:

```
template<class T, class U>
std::common_type_t<T, U>
variadic_min(const T& t, const U& u)
{
   if (t < u)
        std::cout << t << " less than " << u << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << u << " less than " << t << std::endl;
    return t < u ? t : u;
}

template<class First, class Second, class... Rest>
std::common_type_t<First, Second, Rest...>
variadic_min(const First& f, const Second& s, const Rest& ...t )
{
    using ret_t = std::common_type_t<First, Second, Rest...>;
    return variadic_min(variadic_min(static_cast<ret_t>(f), static_cast<ret_t>(s)), static_cast<ret_t>(t)...);
}
```

And then at least you're not victimized by integral promotion; all your types get converted to `unsigned int` so the output is at least predictable; all your negative numbers will become large positive ones:

Output:

```
1 less than 4294967085
1 less than 3
1 less than 4294967233
1 less than 89
Res: 1
```

A better approach in the end might be to be on the lookout for unsigned/signed comparison and then do something special in that case. E.g. check the signed value against zero first and if it's less, then return that one rather than have it cast to a large positive value instead.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile with warnings, you'll see your mistake:

```
<source>:7:11: warning: returning reference to local temporary object [-Wreturn-stack-address]
   return t < u ? t : u;
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
<source>:15:17: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'multi_type_min<float, unsigned int>' requested here
    (( retVal= &multi_type_min(*retVal, t)), ...);
                ^
<source>:28:14: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'variadic_min<float, unsigned int, unsigned int, unsigned int>' requested here
      return variadic_min( z, a,b,c );
             ^
1 warning generated.
```

So you have undefined behavior, as is. Since `T` and `U` may not be the same type, you can't have a common reference/pointer to them both. You need to:

1. Make `multi_type_min` return a value, not a reference.
2. Make `retVal` a value, not a pointer.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,source:'%23include+%3Ctype_traits%3E%0A%0Atemplate+%3Ctypename+T,+typename+U%3E%0Aconst+typename+std::common_type%3CT,+U%3E::type%0Amulti_type_min(const+T%26+t,+const+U%26+u)%0A%7B%0A+++return+t+%3C+u+%3F+t+:+u%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atemplate%3Ctypename+First,+typename+...T%3E%0Atypename+std::common_type%3C++First,+T...%3E::type+%0Avariadic_min(+const+First%26+f,+const+T%26+...t+)%0A%7B%0A++++typename+std::common_type%3C++First,+T...%3E::type+retVal+%3D+f%3B%0A++++((+retVal%3D+multi_type_min(retVal,+t)),+...)%3B%0A%0A++++return+retVal%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%0A%7B%0A++++unsigned+int+a%3D8,+b%3D+2,+c%3D4%3B%0A++++float+z+%3D+43.42f%3B%0A%0A++++//return+variadic_min(1,+-211,3,+-63,+89u)+%3B%0A+++//+return+variadic_min(+89u,+1,+-211,3,+-63)+%3B%0A++++//return+variadic_min(a,b,c,z+)%3B%0A++++++return+variadic_min(+z,+a,b,c+)%3B%0A++++//return+variadic_min(+a,b,c+)%3B%0A%7D'),l:'5',n:'0',o:'C%2B%2B+source+%231',t:'0')),k:39.91361598104351,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:clang400,filters:(b:'0',commentOnly:'0',directives:'0',intel:'0'),options:'-std%3Dc%2B%2B1z++-O3',source:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'x86-64+clang+4.0.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)',t:'0')),k:26.753050685623155,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0'),(g:!((h:output,i:(compiler:2,editor:1),l:'5',n:'0',o:'%232+with+x86-64+clang+4.0.0',t:'0')),k:33.33333333333333,l:'4',n:'0',o:'',s:0,t:'0')),l:'2',n:'0',o:'',t:'0')),version:4):

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename U>
const typename std::common_type<T, U>::type
multi_type_min(const T& t, const U& u)
{
   return t < u ? t : u;
}

template<typename First, typename ...T>
typename std::common_type<  First, T...>::type 
variadic_min( const First& f, const T& ...t )
{
    typename std::common_type<  First, T...>::type retVal = f;
    (( retVal= multi_type_min(retVal, t)), ...);

    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    unsigned int a=8, b= 2, c=4;
    float z = 43.42f;

    return variadic_min( z, a,b,c );
}
```

Here's an alternate implementation that delegates to `std::min` after creating an initializer list based on the common type:

```
template<typename First, typename ...T>
constexpr
typename std::common_type<First, T...>::type 
common_min(const First& f, const T& ...t) {
    std::initializer_list<typename std::common_type<First, T...>::type> ilist = {
        static_cast<typename std::common_type<First, T...>::type>(f),
        static_cast<typename std::common_type<First, T...>::type>(t)...
    };
    return std::min(ilist);
}
```

Comment: values are copied to retval here, are they not?

Comment: @AdamHunyadi: Yes, they are. That's unavoidable.

Comment: Use `common_type< typename decay<T>::type (etc.)` to convert `const ref` types to value types.

Comment: @KhouriGiordano: I don't think it's necessary to decay the type here. I could be wrong, but my understanding was that since the function parameters are already specified to be constant references, the template type would be deduced to be the decayed type already. Though I suppose `std::decay` should be used if you wanted to support the case where the caller explicitly specifies the template types (and they're references).

Comment: @Cornstalks I checked and you're right, decay isn't needed here. Also `common_type` already has decay if there were `T&&` types and T would be `float&`, etc.

Comment: Isn't the warning similar to the dangling references for  rvalues parameter, when result of std::min/std::max captured by reference ? which parameter gets converted to rvalue here ? May be I'm drunk